# SQLException thrown but everything is working

Tags: java, sqlite, exception, sqlexception

I´m connecting my java code to a SQLite db, everything works fine, but an exception is being thrown, and a fail message is showing to the user, why is my code throwing this exception?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection c = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:admin.db");
        System.out.println("Connection established");
        String cmd = "INSERT INTO admins(user_name, password)"
                + "VALUES('TinoCle','1234')";
        Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
        //Executes my command "cmd"
        stmt.execute(cmd);
        //Sends it to the db
        c.commit();
        //Close connection
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } 

    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    catch (SQLException e) {
        //This message is showing up, but it shouldn't
        System.out.println("Connection to DB failed");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you log the exception in your second catch block:  System.out.println(e); Also, usually you want to close your resources in a finally block.

Comment: Can you show the exception stack.

Comment: If you are using the latest version of SQLite, you don't need `Class.forName(...);`.

Comment: The StackTrace sais: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)

Comment: You should print the stack trace.  The message you write to System.out is far less information than the stack trace will give you.  You should be closing resources in a finally block.